# How do I open a file with my application?

Tags: c#-4.0

Ok, you know how in programs like Microsoft Excel, or Adobe Acrobat Reader you can click on a file in explorer and it will open with the associated program. That's what I want my application to do. Now, I know how to set up the file associations in Windows so that it knows the default program for each extension. My question is how do I get my application to open the file when I double click the file.

I've searched the web using google, I've searched the msdn site, and I've searched several forums including this one but I haven't found anything that explains how to accomplish this. I'm guessing it has something to do with the parameters of the main method  but that's just a guess.

If someone can point me in the right direction I can take it from there. Thanks in advance for your help.

Shane

Comment: "Now, I know how to set up the file associations in Windows so that it knows the default program for each extension." If you have set this up then double clicking the file *should* open it in your application. If it doesn't then post your code that does this setting up and someone might be able to tell you why it isn't working.

Answer (score 10):

Setting up the associations in windows will send the filename to your application on the command line.

You need to read the event args in your applications `main` function in order to read the file path and be able to open it in your application.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztbsa4b.aspx) to see how to access the command line arguments in your `main` method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}", args.Length);

    foreach (string s in args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you open the file, with associations set as you described, your application will be started with the first argument containing the filepath to your file.

You can try this out in a simple way by printing out the `args` from your `main` method, after you open your application by clicking on the associated file. The 0th element should be the path to your file.

Now, if you successfully reached this point, the all you need to do now is read the contents of the given file. I'm sure you'll find more than plenty of resources here on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(sfd.FileName); //the file you clicked or saved just point
                                          //to the right file location to determine
                                          //full filename with location info

// opening file
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @fi.FullName;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create registry-keys for your file-extension. [This page](http://www.ubercode.com/write-programs-for-windows-api.html) describes well, which keys you'll need to set (see «3. How do I create file associations?»).