# Get file from "Windows Explorer - Open With"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, parameters, arguments

I'm not quite sure where to start with this. On right-clicking on a generic file in Windows Explorer (e.g. *.doc for a Word document) one can choose "Open with...". I 'd like to know how the program knows what file has been "passed" (is that the right word?). Is it done via arguments? How can I implement this in my own application?

I tried manually adding a file path to the arguments of one of my applications when it is run, but the path includes spaces (which denotes a new argument). How does Windows get round this/what do I need to do to solve this?

Regards,
Robbie

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908955/how-do-i-open-a-file-with-my-application.  Windows should pass the path of the file as the first argument to the associated exe

Comment: @Jason do I have to set my application to be the default one to open files of my designated file type?

Comment: Not simple to add your own file type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144148(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the arguments used from the command line:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sMsg As String = ""
    For Each sArg As String In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
        sMsg &= sArg & ": "
    Next
    MsgBox(sMsg)
End Sub
```

Place the code in the WinForm _Load, Console Main, etc.

If the above was run with:  Hello World as the command line Hello: World: would display.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some VB code to open a file:

```
        Case Keys.F4
            Process.Start("H:\OIS\PROCEDUR\OIS8ProcedureManual.doc")
```

In this case Windows looks up .doc in the file types and uses the .doc entry to run Word and pass it the filename.

Process.Start has a second parameter that contains Arguments so you could provide a path to an .exe in the first param and the argument(s) in the second. Actually there are 5 signatures for Process.start. The most powerful ones uses the ProcessStartInfo class to provide you with the most control.

Post the code you wrote for the second group of questions if the above didn't help.

Comment: I'd like to open a file with my program, not open a file with another program (i.e. rather than opening a file with Word, I want to open a file with my program when the file is double-clicked on in Windows Explorer).

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to accomplish. To get the contents of a file into your program look into System.IO Namespace.

Comment: When I open a file (say "hello world.doc") from Windows Explorer, it automatically opens in Microsoft Word. How would Word in this case know to read the contents of "hello world.doc"?

Comment: Windows Explorer launches a program associated with .doc files. It also provides the filename as a parameter to Word. So, Word has to check the arguments for the process to figure out which file to open.