# c# - use a file to open soft and read from it

Tags: c#, readfile

I want to launch my soft directly by open a file with a specific extension (here no problem) but I was wondering how read directly the content of this file ?

I checked on internet but nothing useful came out.

Thanks

Comment: How do you open the file? Can you show the respective line(s?) of code, please?

Comment: possible duplicate: [How do I open a file with my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4908955/944681)

Comment: @MichalKlouda: Opening is already working, according to the OP.

Comment: Hard to tell, my understanding is, that OP has associated the extension with his application which opens up, but it doesn't process the arguments.

Comment: @MichalKlouda: True, that's also possible ... hence why I asked to see the respective code.

Comment: I think my question is quite complicated, sorry if I don't explain it well, I'd like to bind my soft to a specific extension and read the content of the file opening it. Like when you open a txt file or psd file. Get all the data from this file basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `File` class, in particular the [`File.ReadAllText Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

Sample MSDN usage

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

        // This text is added only once to the file. 
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to. 
            string createText = "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine;
            File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
        }

        // This text is always added, making the file longer over time 
        // if it is not deleted. 
        string appendText = "This is extra text" + Environment.NewLine;
        File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);

        // Open the file to read from. 
        string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
        Console.WriteLine(readText);
    }
}
```

---

In order to read the file name from the command line (invoked on double click)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Console.Writeline("I bet your filename is: {0}", args[0]);
    }
}
```

See also [this very nice example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/main).

Comment: The fact is that I would like to double-click a file and it launch the soft, so I don't know any path, read the file is not a problem

Comment: Yeah perfect, such an idiot, for sure it works like linux ... thank you, I'm used to work on linux, not windows so sometimes I don't make the relation.

Answer (score 0):

[`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx) is waht your looking for, you should provide an Serilizer to get your spezific data from that file.

But what do you want do read from that file? if it is an executable i think you don't want to read that file or?