# Accessing data saved in custom file type in Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I have a windows forms application with a custom file extension set up. I am able to save data to my file, and when I double-click my saved file from Windows, it launches my application.

I have not, however, been able to get the name of the file I clicked on to read in its data. Everything seems to tell me args[0] should be the exe (as I'm seeing), args[1] would be the next parameter (probably what i'm looking for; the file name I clicked on) but args.Length is always just 1, whether I open the exe directly or click on a text file that launches the exe, I never have the file name I clicked on.

Edit (**resolved; ish**): OK, finally have a more specific issue nailed down. My application was deployed with ClickOnce, and I set up all the file associations through the windows forms application properties. When I right-click and view the properties of my saved custom file, it says "Opens with: ClickOnce Application Deployment Support Library" and not my application name. If I change the default to open with my .exe, magically it has the correct arg values (the exe, followed by the file name I clicked on).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I open a file with my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908955/how-do-i-open-a-file-with-my-application)

Comment: Supposedly, you should have your file path in one of the arguments. Are you sure you only have the .exe name?

Comment: If your saved file isn't terribly large, it's often easier to use [File.ReadAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) or [File.ReadAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) than using a `StreamReader`. By the way, you should edit your question so that you don't have all the extra fluff in there. Break it down to just adequately explain your question.

Comment: Thank you; I eliminated the extra info but left enough that it can hopefully help someone else who has this issue but doesn't know what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access command line arguments for ClickOnce applications directly. To get to them, I used the following, modified a bit from [here](http://www.techques.com/question/1-521038/How-do-you-set-up-a-file-association-with-a-click-once-application):

```
System.Runtime.Hosting.ActivationArguments args = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments;
if (args.ActivationData != null)
{
    foreach (string commandLineFile in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Command Line File: {0}", commandLineFile));
    }
}
```

This gave me the file name I clicked on. Hoorah.